# Angular PWA swupdate mensaje: no hay actualizacion disponible

Tags: angular, angular10

Buen día, tengo una PWA con Angular, he puesto un botón para verificar si hay actualizaciones disponibles, la verdad no tengo tan claro como funciona pero hice un servicio copiando código por ahí que me esta funcionando ysi me informa si hay una actualización, pero si no hay quiero mostrarle al usuario algún mensaje y no encuentro donde poner eso, este es mi servicio, si me pueden ayudar lo agradezco de antemano:

```
updateClient2() {
    console.log('en servicio update');
    if (!this.update.isEnabled) {
      console.log('Not Enabled');
      return;
    }
    this.update.available.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(`current`, event.current, `available `, event.available);
      if (confirm('Actualizacion Disponible, confirme')) {
        this.update.activateUpdate().then(() => location.reload());
      }
    });
    this.update.activated.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(`current`, event.previous, `available `, event.current);
    });
  }

  public checkForUpdates(): void {
    console.log('checando updates en servicio....');
    this.updateSubscription = this.update.available.subscribe(event => this.promptUser());
    if (this.update.isEnabled) {
        // Required to enable updates on Windows and ios.
        this.update.activateUpdate();
        this.update.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
          console.log('checking for updates');
      });
    }else{
      console.log('no hay');
    }
}

promptUser(): void {
    this.update.activateUpdate().then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: tienes varias validaciones que no entiendo bien cual es la que ejecutas, puedes agregar tu componente o la parte de tu componente donde lo mandas llamar.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, pues el llamado es muy simple, mas bien creo que no comprendo bien lo que hace el update, es codigo que he copiado y no me queda tan claro como funciona, el llamado es desde un componente asi:  update(){
    console.log('en Update...');
    this.updateService.updateClient2();
    this.updateService.checkForUpdates();
  }